# Discord OAuth2 redirect URI how-to

Tags: oauth-2.0, uri, bots

I'm trying to make a discord bot (with the bot tag) that can join other servers.

I will be able to do this, if I can set up a redirect URI for it. I already have the bot account set up, and it already functions with it (except for joining servers).

I was wondering how to set up a redirect URI for discord OAuth2?

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 7):

To add your bot to a server you need to make a redirect url with your Client ID

Just replace the Client Id with your Client Id:

```
https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?&client_id=[CLIENTID]&scope=bot
```

That's all! Now you just need to click on it!

Comment: bot do not provide all access which have user

Answer (score 3):

You need to have your own webserver with some path to make your redirect url. For example, if you owned example.com, you could have example.com/discord be the url to redirect the client to after they login via Discord.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are trying to use the guilds.join scope and it tells you to give a redirect URI. I think you are mistaking the guilds.join for the bot because it is actually the scope for letting your application join servers for the client (you can see this by going on the link `https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?&client_id=[CLIENTID]&scope=guilds.join` and replace `[CLIENTID]` with the application client ID).
This means the link with the scope guilds.join will be on a website that you own and once the user either grants and denies this, the grant page will redirect the client back to the website.

Also, your bot cannot actually self-join servers simply because of how it was made. Bots must be manually authorized through OAuth. If you want a bot to join the server itself, it could use the invite link to get the server and DM the server owner (that can be found using the property) a OAuth link for the bot. Since the bot is not in the server it wants to join, you will need to do this method through the rest client. If you don't mind doing it like other bots, you can get the bot to provide the join link like other bots with a command like `!invite`.

Edit: If you want more information about using guilds.join, the documentation link is here: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member